# Do I need a Visual Studio Professional license to use SQL Server Data Tools for business purposes?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I have an old server with SQL Server 2016 installed which also has Visual Studio 2015 installed so I can use SQL Server Data Tools to build cubes & reports.

I need to reinstall / update this content on a new server, but am confused about Visual Studio licensing. Unfortunately the person who set up the server initially is no longer available.

Do I now need to pay for a monthly/annual Visual Studio Professional license to install it for just this purpose?

I cannot find any details on the license on the old server, it just says 'Licensed'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licensing questions are explicitly off-topic for [so], sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the free [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/).  This is explicitly called out in the license:

> iv. Any number of your users may use the software only for Microsoft SQL Server development when using the SQL Server Data Tools or the extensions “Microsoft Analysis Services Projects”, “Microsoft Reporting Services Projects”, or “SQL Server Integration Services Projects” to develop Microsoft SQL Server database projects or Analysis Services, Reporting Services, Power BI Report Server, or Integration Services projects.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/vs2022-ga-community/